# SQL Divide output not working

Tags: sql, t-sql

the code below is giving the result rounded up by a decimal place.

i.e

`123 abandoned calls`/`2473 Call volume`*`100` should give me `4.97` but is showing `5.00` any idea how to fix this?

```
convert (Decimal (10,2),Cast (Abandoned as decimal(10,2))/Cast ([Call Volumes] as decimal(10,2)))*100 as Abandon_Rate
```

Comment: move the `*100` inside the last `)`

Comment: You could also just multiple 123 by 1.0. Then divide by 2473 and multiple by 100. Like so: `SELECT (Abandoned * 1.0) / [Call Volumes] * 100 as Abandon_Rate`

Comment: try using `100.0` instead of `100`

Answer (score 0):

You could move 100 to the front, and only need to cast once:

```
SELECT 100 * Cast (Abandoned as decimal(10,2))/[Call Volumes] as Abandon_Rate
```

The result should be something like this:

```
Abandon_Rate
--------------------
4.9737161342498
```